# Extract Time from date time in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to extract the time part from a column which is of type varchar(16 char).

### HIT_TIME

01/01/2022 21:52

I want to extract just the time from above example.

Comment: `SUBSTR(hit_time, 12)` will give you the time component; however, storing dates as strings is bad practice and you should consider changing your table to use a `DATE` column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TO_DATE` function to convert the string to a date type. Then `TO_CHAR` function formats the time part of the date.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(HIT_TIME, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'), 'HH24:MI') AS only_time
FROM table;
```

I also created a fiddle to demonstrate the query - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4729ee/1

Comment: I have tried to convert to date and to char but it doesn't work it gives error

Comment: @ARH seems to be working for me. What kind of error you get? I created a fiddle where you can see it - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4729ee/1

Comment: Don't use a to_date on unstructured data. This can, and thus will, lead to an error.  2nd: you can't see the exact format based on his one example. When the TS wants the last 5 chars, he better uses a substr() as already commented on his question.

Comment: @hetOrakel of course it's better to store dates as dates. But if ARH wants date this gets the date. Yes, in case data is different it fails but thr same does substring - not necessarilly an error but it returns you nonsense results.